# js, when drop file, not to open it

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying make a drag and drop function and I have read a lot of references.

When I make my own. When I drop a file, the browser will automatically load and renew the page to dropped file as the default what it will do. Thereby, the dragover and drop events are not firing.

```
el.on('dragover', function(){
    alert(1);
});

el.on('drop', function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

I checked those examples, but I couldnt find a specific line for remove this default reload function from browser.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `preventDefault()` method of the argument of the function.
See exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/kze6V/

```
document.addEventListener('drop', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Comment: I checked your example...yes works, but even I add e.preventDefault(); the browner will just load the dropped file on my example. Does jquery supports $el.on('drop') ???

Comment: Sure, see [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/kze6V/1/) of the fiddle to see how to restrict the event to a JQuery element using `on`. However don't forget to use `e.originalEvent` instead of `e` to access the dropped files.